# All ways to write tausendmal?

Tags: grammatical-number, time

I've got a few songs with the term *tausendmal* in them. So far I've seen *tausendmal*, *tausend Mal*, *tausend mal*, *1000 mal*.

I looked on the internet and also found *1000-mal*

Are all these acceptable and can be used in writing? If so, does this apply to all numbers?

Answer (score 3):

The most definitive rule set - [rules of the German Rechtschreibrat](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/) - says in §39:

> Mehrteilige Adverbien, Konjunktionen, Präpositionen und Pronomen schreibt  man  zusammen,  wenn  die  Wortart,  die  Wortform  oder  die Bedeutung der einzelnen Bestandteile nicht mehr deutlich erkennbar ist.

And mentions these explicit examples (there are more number examples in the word list they publish)

> **-mal**     diesmal, einmal, zweimal, keinmal, manchmal

With an exception in E2:

> E2: In anderen Fällen schreibt man getrennt. Siehe auch § 39 E3(1).
>
> Dies betrifft
>
> 1. Fälle, bei denen ein Bestandteil erweitert ist, zum Beispiel:
>    *dies eine Mal* (aber diesmal)

Elaborating from these rules it is clear it needs to be

> **tausendmal**

The word list mentions another exception: If you want to put specific emphasis on the number, you can write in two words, but definitely with an upper-case "Mal":

> das achte Mal, zum achten Mal[e] (aber achtmal, bei besonderer Betonung auch
> acht Mal, 8 Mal)

(Last example "8 Mal" was found in the word list under "achtseitig")

All your other examples are strictly speaking wrong.

And yes, this applies to all numbers and even non-numbers, like *keinmal, dutzendmal, diesmal, manchmal*,...)

Answer (score 2):

Correct are **(ein)tausendmal** and **(ein)tausend Mal(e)**. Writing small or simple numbers with digits instead of number-words is considered bad style.

Comment: _... is considered bad style_ by whom? And according to which authority the versions of _tausend mall_ you've listed are the correct ones?

Answer (score 2):

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tausendmal) sagt es heißt:

> tausendmal
>
> Bedeutung: tausend Male

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/tausendmal) sagt es heißt:

> tausendmal
>
> Alternative Schreibweisen: 1000-mal, bei Betonung: tausend Mal, 1000 Mal

I would trust Duden on the correct spelling: *tausendmal* or *tausend Mal*.
The alternative spellings (*1000-mal* and *1000 Mal*) are slang and therefore there is no correct way to write it. I've seen *1000mal* to save space in sms.

Comment: Ich muss bei Formulierungen wie "Wikipedia sagt" immer schlucken. "Der Brockhaus sagt" oder "Der Duden sagt" sind akzeptabel, weil hinter diesen Werken Redaktionen stehen, die die Beiträge nach einem strengen System abstimmen. Wikis funktionieren anders. Insbesondere kann jedermann schnell etwas hineinschreiben; dies wird zwar, wenn offenkundig falsch, in der Regel schnell korrigiert, doch wird es bei NIschenthemen sowie ideologisch problematischen Dingen schwierig, sich auf W. zu beziehen. Ich zöge vor man sagte: "Im entsprechenden Wikipedia-Artikel finde ich dazu..."

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Im Moment ist dies die einzige Antwort, die _überhaupt_ Quellen angibt.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, Duden hängt der Umgangssprache immer ein wenig hinterher, so, dass ich es berechtigt finde Wiktionary als zusätzliche Quelle (die einzige, die alternative Schreibweisen angibt) zu erwähnen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Was genau sollte falsch daran sein, zu sagen, was Sache ist? Natürlich "sagt Wikipedia". Das ist vollkommen ohne Wertung, genauso wie "der Ahnungslose sagt" oder "der Experte sagt" oder gar "der Politiker sagt". Und es ist vollkommen wertungsgleich zu "...ich finde dazu". Tut mir leid, aber was ChristianGeiselmann hier sagt, ist Unsinn.